# Timestamp overlapping matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph using matplotlib with number of requests (y-axis) vs timestamp (x-axis in HH:MM format).
This graph will show the pattern for the all the requests received between 6:00 AM to 6:00 PM. Below is the sample data. Actual data has more than 500 entries.

```
time_stamp = ['06:02', '06:03', '06:12', '06:16', '06:17', '06:27', '06:28', '06:30', '06:31', '06:34', '06:35', '06:36', '06:37', '06:38', '06:39', '06:40', '06:41', '06:42', '06:43']
requests = [74, 20, 2, 1, 11, 9, 34, 3, 5, 4, 28, 77, 75, 73, 122, 99, 170, 79, 44, 79, 100, 58, 104, 84, 77, 98, 27]
```

Below is the script which I am using to generate the graph. Problem which I am facing currently is overlapping of all the timestamps on the x-axis.

**Script:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TITLE = 'Time (Per Minute) Vs Num of Requests Graph'

X_AXIS_NAME = 'TimeStamps (per minute)'
Y_AXIS_NAME = 'No. of Requests'

time_stamp = ['06:02', '06:03', '06:12', '06:16', '06:17', '06:27', '06:28', 
              '06:30', '06:31', '06:34', '06:35', '06:36', '06:37', '06:38', '06:39', 
              '06:40', '06:41', '06:42', '06:43', '06:44', '06:45', '06:46', '06:47', 
              '06:48', '06:49', '06:50', '06:51', '06:52', '06:53', '06:54', '06:55', 
              '06:56', '06:57', '06:58', '06:59', '07:00', '07:01']

requests = [74, 20, 2, 1, 11, 9, 34, 3, 5, 4, 28, 77, 75, 73]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(time_stamp, requests)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel(X_AXIS_NAME)
plt.ylabel(Y_AXIS_NAME)
plt.title(TITLE)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('graph.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

**Generated Graph:**

[image]

And this is the graph which I actually want to generate. This graph has been generated using Excel.

**Expected Graph:**

Timestamps are not overlapped.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

```
dates = []
for ts in time_stamp:
    dates.append( datetime.strptime(ts, '%H:%M'))
mp_dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(mp_dates, requests)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
dates = []
for ts in time_stamp:
    local_d = datetime.strptime(ts, '%H:%M')
    dates.append( local_d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.plot(dates, requests)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
#fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel(X_AXIS_NAME)
plt.ylabel(Y_AXIS_NAME)
plt.title(TITLE)

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
fig.savefig('graph.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

[image]

Only missing piece is to reduce the interval between 2 ticks. Currently it is 2 hours.

Any help or pointer in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: Usual problem: You are plotting strings. If you want to show real dates, plot dates instead of strings. There are enough examples on that around.

Comment: Yeah , i had googled about that and tried to change the string timestamps into matplotlib dates but no luck. Please see EDIT 1.

Comment: That's fow sure the way to go. `plt.plot(dates, requests)` should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that but is also showing day and month also on the x axis e.g. 01-01 06 , 01-01 08 ... and so on. Ideally it should be only hours and mins.
Also there is gap of 2 hrs between 2 labels. Any way we can reduce it ?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem of displaying hours and mins on x axis. Only missing piece in the puzzle is to adjust the interval between two ticks. currently it is set as 2 hours. I have to reduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research finally I am able to plot it.

```
dates = []
for ts in time_stamp:
   local_d = datetime.strptime(ts, '%H:%M')
   dates.append( local_d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.plot(dates, requests)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=20))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.xlabel(X_AXIS_NAME)
plt.ylabel(Y_AXIS_NAME)
plt.title(TITLE)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('graph.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

[image]

Thanks to the community!

Answer (score 0):

For just fully rotating the labels like in your excel plot. Try this.

```
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

Comment: Actually rotation is the secondary issue , primary issue is , I have too many values on x axis to plot which is causing the overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use matplotlib's `autofmt_xdate()` method to solve the problem you're facing.

Just add following line before `plt.show()`

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

The defaults work well, so most probably you can just call it without any parameters, but for the sake of completeness, you can use parameters specified below.

Quoting [matplotlib documentation (v.3.1.1)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html):

> `autofmt_xdate(self, bottom=0.2, rotation=30, ha='right', which=None)`
>
> Date ticklabels often overlap, so it is useful to rotate them and right align them. Also, a common use case is a number of subplots with shared xaxes where the x-axis is date data. The ticklabels are often long, and it helps to rotate them on the bottom subplot and turn them off on other subplots, as well as turn off xlabels.
> Parameters:
>
> - `bottom : scalar`
>
>   The bottom of the subplots for subplots_adjust().
> - `rotation : angle in degrees`
>
>   The rotation of the xtick labels.
> - `ha : string`
>
>   The horizontal alignment of the xticklabels.
> - `which : {None, 'major', 'minor', 'both'}`
>
>   Selects which ticklabels to rotate. Default is None which works the same as major

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the many data but the density of tick labels. `autofmt_xdate` even fails with a few labelled ticks if the figure is narrow. So the solution is to reduce the number of labelled ticks. No rotation is needed if only full hours are labelled without printing minutes. Note that `MinuteLocator(interval=60)` would fail -- silently placing ticks with an offset of a fractional hour.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from numpy import arange # for fake x data

y = [3, 30, 3000, 2900, 3100, 1000, 3000, 2000, 200, 20, 2] # roughly
x = arange(len(y))*dt.timedelta(seconds=4800) + dt.datetime.strptime('05:50', '%H:%M')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
ax.set_title('Request Load (<server> <service> <date>)')
ax.set_xlabel('time of day in hours (timezone)')
ax.set_ylabel('requests per minute')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H'))
ax.set_ylim(0)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]